# Uploading a JSON through Dropzone: acceptedFiles: doesnt recognise json

Tags: dropzone.js, vue-dropzone

I am trying to upload a JSON through Dropzone.
The MIME type for JSON through acceptedFiles doesn't seem to be recognised.

Already tried:
  acceptedFiles: 'application/json'; and
  acceptedFiles: '.json';

When using 'application/json', dropzone doesnt recognise json file types so I am unable to upload a file.

When using '.json', I am able to upload a file but it turns into 'application/octet-stream'.

What do i need to use to upload a JSON and it be an accepted file type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by updating Google Chrome.